# openpyxl: Return absolute path from excel hyperlink openpyxl windows environment

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I have an excel file and hyperlinks are added using ctrl & k. I want to ultimately check that the link exists, but for the moment, I need to grab the absolute path of the file as the locations of the file will often change.

This results in hyperlinks in the excel file like "file.pdf" or "../../file.pdf"

Using Openpyxl, I can grab the hyperlink target:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:\sample\sample.xlsx')
ws = wb['Index']

for row in ws.iter_rows():
    try:
        print( print(row[4].hyperlink.target))
        p = Path(row[4].hyperlink.target).resolve() # does not resolve into "C:\...."
        print(str(p))
    except:
        pass
```

How can I grab the absolute path from the hyperlink?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with abspath..

```
import openpyxl
from os.path import abspath

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:\sample\sample.xlsx')
ws = wb['Index']

for row in ws.iter_rows():
    try:
        print( print(row[4].hyperlink.target))
        p = abspath(row[4].hyperlink.target) #"C:\folder\link.pdf"
        print(p)
    except:
        pass
```